# Pandas to CSV inaccurate write too

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Below is a simple whois ip searcher which takes in a csv named dupfree.csv...

[image: dupfree.csv]

Above is my example file. Presently when I run the below script I make it through the process but the copy of the data frame to the CSV appears to be copying the response for item x in all rows. Then it adds a new Row + Header and adds data for the other IP. Not sure what im doing wrong its clearly processing the data just not matching the index with the calling IP.

[image: Successful Run]

As you can see from the debug we are running this across both items.

```
def main ():
    df = pd.read_csv('dupfree.csv')
    temp = whoisyou(df)

        
def whoisyou(df):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.settimeout(10)
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        DN = df.iloc[index]['ip']
        ipwhois = IPWhois(DN).lookup_rdap()
        df['network'] = ipwhois['asn_cidr']
        df['cidr'] = ipwhois['asn_description']
        df['country'] = ipwhois['asn_country_code']
        df['date'] = ipwhois['asn_date']
        DN = df.iloc[index]['ip']
        print (DN)
        print (df['date'])
        with open('csv_data.txt', 'w') as csv_file:
            df.to_csv('output.csv', header = True, mode='a')
            time.sleep (.5)
```

Below is the outcome received from the above script run. As you can see it reflects data for both hosts but its found inside a completely new header.

[image: output.csv]

Thank you All

Comment: `df.to_csv('output.csv', header = True, mode='a')` running inside your loop...

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to the CSV with `header = True` inside your loop. Use a variable for the `header` to write it just once... e.g.

```
def whoisyou(df):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.settimeout(10)
    header = True
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        DN = df.iloc[index]['ip']
        ipwhois = IPWhois(DN).lookup_rdap()
        df['network'] = ipwhois['asn_cidr']
        df['cidr'] = ipwhois['asn_description']
        df['country'] = ipwhois['asn_country_code']
        df['date'] = ipwhois['asn_date']
        DN = df.iloc[index]['ip']
        print (DN)
        print (df['date'])
        with open('csv_data.txt', 'w') as csv_file:
            df.to_csv('output.csv', header = header, mode='a')
            header = False
            time.sleep (.5)
```

There's probably a nicer way to achieve the same, but the above should work.